# C2011 "..." : 'class' type redefinition problem C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have small problem with my code. I've tried like 20 posts and not even single solution has worked. Maybe it's other problem. I don't know. Can anybody help me? I can't pass it on my own.

rootTe.h

```
#pragma once
class Root { 
public:
double a, b, c, x1, x2, x;

Root(double, double, double); //inline?

void roots(unsigned int);

double getX1();
double getX2();
double getX();
};
```

rootTe.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "rootException.h" 
#include "rootTest.h"

class Root { 
public:
double a, b, c, x1, x2, x;

Root(double a2, double b2, double c2) {
    a = a2;
    b = b2;
    c = c2;
}

void roots(unsigned int m) {
    ...
}

double getX1() {
    return x1;
}

double getX2() {
    return x2;
}

double getX() {
    return x;
}
};
```

Comment: "*I have a small problem with my code*" - can you describe it?

Comment: Please have a look at a C++ text book. Words like `class` and `public` only appear in .h files, not in .cpp files. Instead you would need tho have text like `double Root::getX1() ...` Have you been a C# or Java programmer before?

Comment: When I try to run it, there is error like you can see inside the title. I've tried to add inline, create Root::Root inside .h file, delete everything except oot(double a2, double b2, double c2) from rootTe.cpp Root initialization and adding initialization into Root::Root inside .h ...

Comment: Well, I won't lie. Java.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the class `Root` twice.

In C++, using separate declaration and definition, you should use the following snipped:

```
#include "rootTest.h"

Root::Root(double a2, double b2, double c2) {
    a = a2;
    b = b2;
    c = c2;
}

void Root::roots(unsigned int m) {
    ...
}
```

And so on.

Comment: `s/declaring/defining/`. Otherwise it wouldn't be a redefinition error.

Comment: Done! Thank you @juan

Comment: It works. You rock! I could do it "easy" way, but now it looks like I want it to look, like it should look. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, remember to accept the answer as correct, so stackoverflow can keep growing :)